# jQuery animation on drop down is jerky, slow and unresponsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I have some fairly simple animation on a drop down menu which seems to jerk a hell of a lot and quite often becomes unresponsive. It occurs in Firefox and Internet Explorer.

The jQuery code used:

```
$(".optionslink").hover(function() { 
        $(".dropdown").stop(true,true);

        $(".dropdown").animate({opacity: 100, top: '30px'},200);
        $(".optionslink").css("background-color","#444");
    }, function() { 
        $(".dropdown").animate({top: -$(".dropdown").height(), opacity: 0}, 400);
        $(".optionslink").css("background-color","transparent");
    }
);
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="optionslink" style="background-color: transparent;">                                
    <a class="optionslinka" href="">Options <img alt="" src="/web/resources/graphics/lightdownarrow.gif"></a>
    <div class="dropdown" style="opacity: 0; top: -86px;">  
        Drop down text / links here                         
    </div>                          
</div>
```

Can anyone offer some advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does removing the image improve the performance? With older browsers rendering images "in motion" like that can act as a bottleneck. Is there a way you can try it as a CSS background image? Although with a name like "light down arrow" I'm guessing it's not a very large image.

EDIT: Ran it through jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/J7QuV/ I just ran it on IE7 in IETester as well and it's also very fast, I think IE7's JS implementation is much slower than FF as well.

What kind of content is this dropping over, if any? that might be the part I'm missing in the test.

Comment: Good idea. However the image itself is within the link that triggers the animation, it has no animation itself and doesn't move / fade at all - would your answer still apply given the case?

Comment: Is it slow in all browsers, or is there one in particular?

Comment: FF / IE... Chrome seems fine but it then again it is leagues ahead in Javascript performance